# Flashing question mark appears after wake from sleep when charging Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

My laptop is a Macbook Pro 2017 non-touchbar. When the Macbook goes into sleep mode while it charges, most of the time the flashing question mark appears when I try to wake it up. I can't do anything but to force shutdown when this problem occurs. If I *don’t* plug in the charger and it goes into sleep mode, everything is normal when it wakes up.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, yet? I am having the exact same issue (Model ). I've already been to the apple store and they ran some tests, but couldn't detect anything. They told me to reinstall mac, but of cause that didn't help. For now I need to boot the mac approx. 20 times until it finally boots. No idea what is different when it finally works..

Comment: I were able to narrow it down to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/389438/368745).
I plan on going to the Apple Store again with this knowledge, but I guess replacing the battery is my only real chance of fixing this issue. Problem is I'm not spending 100 bucks for a "it might work again".