# MacBook shows flashing question mark in a folder when battery is at > 70%

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery

I am sure many of you guys know the flashing folder icon which shows up when the Mac cannot find a drive to boot from. My 2017 MacBook Pro has this issue for some time now, but recently I found something interesting.

The MBP won't find the boot drive, as long as **the battery level is at > 70%**.

The Mac boots just fine at lower battery levels; no issues whatsoever. Now, the problem is, I don't want to run my MacBook via battery the whole time or keep on disconnecting the AC power when 70% is reached every time.

Does anybody have similar symptoms and did find a better solution? Do you think there is a hardware issue with my device?

I've been to the Apple store before (when I didn't knew this was connected to the battery level) and they couldn't find anything. They suggested I reinstall macOS, which of cause didn't change anything.

**Edit**:
One detail I forgot to mention was that when I charge my MBP and close the lid, it crashes and gets really hot (fans turn on slowly). I'm not totally sure on this, but I think this also happens with lower battery levels.

**Battery Info**:

[image]

Comment: When people lead with “reinstall the OS” it means they’re guessing.  The battery charge should have nothing to do with whether your boot device is found.  The next thing you should try is an *external* drive like a USB. Just do a clean install on a 32GB flash or larger and lets see if the symptoms persist when you have a full charge. It should find that boot volume automatically, but you may Have to hold `Opt` at boot to the USB.

Comment: Thank you. I installed Catalina on an USB Stick and booting from it works fine, regardless of the battery level. If the battery level is high, the internal ssd is not shown on boot (holding Opt), in disk utility or diskutil. Any conclusions?

Comment: You might have a swollen battery, a faulty charging circuit or a bad SSD.  I would start looking at the battery as it’s about 3 years old now and well within the failure window.  Also, see if you can try (or have a tech) try a different SSD.  If those don’t solve it, you have a logic board issue.  This is what Apple should have done.  Not make you reinstall the OS.

Comment: @Allan "swollen battery" my first guess yesterday when I saw this question! but I thought is it really possible to swell that much in 30% charge capacity, so I didn't comment but "followed" it for someone else to say so. `^_^'`. Post an answer :)

Comment: The 70% battery is not a fixed value, at least that's not what I experienced. My MBP booted with 89% left a couple of times. I always made sure to follow the official Apple guidelines on how to keep your battery healthy..

Can you further explain how I can check the battery and the ssd? I thought the SSD is soldered to the logic board?

I found a Battery Replacement Program which specifically mentions 2017 MBP, but it says that my device is not eligible (either not affected, already replaced (which its not) or not eligible anymore)

Comment: Some infos on my battery here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDDZa.jpg

Comment: @Josh only think sticking out is manufacturer of the battery though I'm not sure if that is the battery supplier for this model. Also, `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` gives similar info too.

Comment: I was pretty close in my guess as to the age, but swelling has nothing to do with age (per se) , cycles or use.  It has to do with the inability of the battery to vent the off gasses.  If they become trapped (like from a manufacturing defect) it will swell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the symptoms and the fact that you have no problem booting from an external devices means it could be, in order of most to least likely, the following:

- Defective battery
- Logic Board
- SSD Drive

The battery and SSD are "simple" to diagnose, but not very convenient (unless you've actually got a shop and spare batteries and Mac proprietary SSDs laying about)<sup>*</sup>.  Basically, you would try "known good" components to see if the problem goes away.  The logic board is the most difficult as you would need to either eliminate everything else as a possibility or use specialized tools to verify that the SMC and related components (i.e. power rails) were functioning properly.

> If the battery level is high, the internal ssd is not shown on boot (holding Opt),

What we know is that *everything works so long as the battery level is not high* because it tells us that the computer will boot and do everything it's supposed to but it won't see the actual drive itself; it's not just a missing file system.

A battery can swell and push everything out of alignment just enough to break contact with components.

The SSD could be failing since it's the only component that actually "disappears" from the system, but it works fine otherwise. Since the SSDs aren't SATA anymore and are now directly connected to the PCIe bus, you should be experiencing other difficulties and not just the SSD in isolation.

The reason I put the logic board higher in probability than the SSD is because the circuitry (managed by the SMC) is what regulates voltage.  Regardless of the charge or from where it's coming from (mains or battery) the SMC "system" ensures that the correct voltage gets to where it's going.  In other words, the voltage to the PCIe bus and ultimately to the SSD doesn't fluctuate.  If it does, then the problem is with the logic board, not the battery.

Either way, if and once you elminate the battery as a cause, you'll need to take your machine in for service.  Apple will have you replace the logic board, however a specialist (i.e. [Rossman Repair](https://www.rossmanngroup.com/); not affiliated, just a satisfied customer) might be able to find and replace the actual bad component at a far lower price.

---

<sup>*</sup> The 2015 and earlier MacBook Pro laptops had a removable SSD whereas the 2016 and later models have a soldered on SSD.  They can still be replaced, however it will have to be done by someone with the proper tools and skill-set for SMT PCB rework.  I left this info in for people with the same issue but earlier MacBook models.

Comment: How can I eliminate the battery as a cause? And does argumentation still hold because when I boot the MBP with 50% battery from its internal ssd and then charge it to 100% it works just fine, as long as I dont put it in sleep or turn it off?

Comment: Admittedly, you're is a weird case.  In that scenario, you might have to wait to see if the SSD gets disconnected after a period of time being fully charged (i.e. leave it charged for a while or even reboot).  But, to diagnose the battery, you'd have to swap it out - it's one of the few user interchangeable parts left on a Mac these days.

Comment: Okay, thank you! In my experience as long as the MBP is running, there are no issues. I had it that i plugged in a monitor (where the monitor turns black for a second and it just crashed (blinking icon). Batteries are quite expensive sadly.

Comment: In the automotive industry parlance, they would say yours wasn't a "[Wednesday Motor](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wednesday%20motor)."  It's such an interesting glitch I'd love to see the final result.

Comment: Will keep you upated. Of cause this happens right after the two year legal warranty runs out...

Comment: Another question: Do you think there is a workaround in which I can keep my MBP connected to AC power and still use the internal SSD? It would just need to stop charging at around 60% to be safe. Maybe in the end it doesn't matter if the battery is used quite heavily from now on, if it is defect anyway.

Comment: Update: I fixed the issue completely by replacing the internal ssd with an adapter and a 2242 nvme ssd. The battery is not able to push onto the ssd or the logic board, because its located *below* the board. Anyways, the battery is draining relatively fast on standby, but that's it. Thanks for the help, all!

On another note: Putting in the nvme ssd in increased my storage from 128gb to 512gb, which is nice :)